# Stormpath and Heroku

Tags: heroku, stormpath

I've been trying to launch the Stormpath tutorial app to Heroku, but Heroku is telling me 'An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.  If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.'

I checked the logs and the main thing seems to be 'Error: API key ID and secret is required.', but I have no idea what that's supposed to mean.  I already followed the guide here https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app and set the key ID and secret in the terminal.  What do I do to make this thing launch on Heroku properly?

Everything runs just fine locally and here is the full log:

```
2016-05-23T00:57:21.912777+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-05-23T00:57:21.912752+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T00:57:21.912773+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-webapp@1.0.0 start /app
2016-05-23T00:57:21.912778+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236038+00:00 app[web.1]: error:  Error: API key ID and secret is required.
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236061+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236061+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fn (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236062+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236060+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ValidateClientConfigStrategy.process (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:33:12)
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236056+00:00 app[web.1]:     at newError (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:15:14)
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236065+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236066+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:534:15)
2016-05-23T00:57:23.236066+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:514:5)
2016-05-23T00:58:19.594432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-05-23T00:58:19.594683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-05-23T00:58:20.928062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-23T00:58:20.879933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-05-23T00:58:40.721955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=a8142cf5-0e42-402b-b777-69aa7867808a fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T00:58:41.882687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=04db8c96-ff75-4535-9aa9-cb1415951742 fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:00:10.489523+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by brandonlum94@gmail.com
2016-05-23T01:00:10.489494+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7873309 by brandonlum94@gmail.com
2016-05-23T01:00:10.619075+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-05-23T01:00:10.619085+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-05-23T01:00:10.966086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-23T01:00:12.625037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-23T01:00:15.420889+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T01:00:15.420908+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-webapp@1.0.0 start /app
2016-05-23T01:00:15.420911+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-05-23T01:00:15.420912+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939751+00:00 app[web.1]: error:  Error: API key ID and secret is required.
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939761+00:00 app[web.1]:     at newError (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:15:14)
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939763+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ValidateClientConfigStrategy.process (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:33:12)
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939764+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fn (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939765+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939765+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939767+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939769+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:534:15)
2016-05-23T01:00:16.939770+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:514:5)
2016-05-23T01:01:13.074993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-05-23T01:01:13.074993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-05-23T01:01:13.918547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-23T01:01:13.916299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-05-23T01:01:16.688198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=b8b03962-66f9-4b67-be55-009dff78c8b0 fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:01:17.984769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=5a6a9d91-a144-415c-9293-951aedc0f26b fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:02:40.694187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=b004fcf9-f3d8-482f-bae3-3e4cfe90160e fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:02:41.552456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=80a2b214-7a03-4a32-b09d-7ed210685b1e fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:04:23.179785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=47a5a69e-b26b-4318-9c34-869a1f488e54 fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:04:24.057028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=1736845b-b276-435d-ac09-dd308592f290 fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:07:39.697756+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by brandonlum94@gmail.com
2016-05-23T01:07:39.697756+00:00 heroku[api]: Set STORMPATH_SECRET_KEY config vars by brandonlum94@gmail.com
2016-05-23T01:07:40.390722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-23T01:07:42.158518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-23T01:07:44.211079+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T01:07:44.211110+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-webapp@1.0.0 start /app
2016-05-23T01:07:44.211113+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-05-23T01:07:44.211119+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303304+00:00 app[web.1]: error:  Error: API key ID and secret is required.
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303317+00:00 app[web.1]:     at newError (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:15:14)
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303318+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ValidateClientConfigStrategy.process (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:33:12)
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303319+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fn (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303320+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303320+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303321+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303321+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303322+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303324+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:514:5)
2016-05-23T01:07:45.303323+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:534:15)
2016-05-23T01:08:42.173794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-05-23T01:08:42.173889+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-05-23T01:08:42.972327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-23T01:08:42.960998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-05-23T01:08:42.973810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-23T01:08:44.895681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-23T01:08:47.490885+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T01:08:47.490893+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-webapp@1.0.0 start /app
2016-05-23T01:08:47.490900+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-23T01:08:47.490899+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673636+00:00 app[web.1]: error:  Error: API key ID and secret is required.
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673657+00:00 app[web.1]:     at newError (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:15:14)
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673659+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ValidateClientConfigStrategy.process (/app/node_modules/stormpath-config/lib/strategy/ValidateClientConfigStrategy.js:33:12)
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673660+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fn (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673660+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673661+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673665+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:534:15)
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673661+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673666+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:514:5)
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673662+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
2016-05-23T01:08:48.673664+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1206:34)
2016-05-23T01:09:44.945559+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2016-05-23T01:09:44.916097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-05-23T01:09:44.916097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-05-23T01:09:45.800059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2016-05-23T01:09:45.849441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-23T01:17:24.998834+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=f573e1ab-6029-4115-b925-3034b93ca7dc fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:17:25.895402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=eca422af-0a7c-4d10-9bd6-16fc54b6b10d fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:21:00.461372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=89189a45-6415-48e4-be08-0fb2a83291e8 fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-23T01:21:01.050242+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=workpls.herokuapp.com request_id=6d4fa6d5-1feb-4a10-8864-ef50fe72845b fwd="73.222.253.89" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Hi there, can you tell us the names of the environment variables that you have setup for the heroku application? Please see the documentation of the express-stormpath module for the correct names.  Thanks!

Comment: set STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID=YOUR_ID_HERE  set STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET=YOUR_SECRET_HERE  
set STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF=YOUR_APP_HREF //Sorry for the formatting.  I have already set those 3 variables according to the guide linked in the original post.  I got my API key and secret key from the file I downloaded in the Stormpath console as well as the href in the application details.

Answer (score 0):

I work at Stormpath, so just hopping in here. We recently released a new version of our express-stormpath library, which looks for environment variables with different names than those which are included by default on Heroku.

I'm going to fix this in the Heroku documentation right now.

What you can do to get things working in the interim is this:

```
$ heroku config:set STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF=$(heroku config:get STORMPATH_URL)
$ heroku config:set STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID=$(heroku config:get STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID)
$ heroku config:set STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET=$(heroku config:get STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET)
```

Those above commands will duplicate your Heroku environment variables for Stormpath, naming them correctly.

Sorry for the confusion, I'm working on getting this fixed right now =)

Comment: I tried: STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF:     XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID:     XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

STORMPATH_SECRET_KEY:           XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  

STORM_PATH_SECRET_KEY:          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: That last one is invalid, you spelled STORMPATH wrong, it should be STORMPATH not STORM_PATH.

Comment: I have the correctly spelled one as the 4th entry: "STORMPATH_SECRET_KEY:           XXXXXXXXXX".  How do you make new lines   in the comments?  I typed heroku config in the terminal and it says the href, apikey_id, and apikey_secret are the ones I set for my application.

Comment: No, what I mean is, they need to be set to: `STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID`, `STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET`, and `STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF` (just like in my example code).

Comment: I'm getting: "!    config:get is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar."  I'm on Windows command prompt and I tried your code as is.  Do I have to change something?  I tried heroku config:set STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF=STORMPATH_URL, but it's invalid in the logs.  Here is heroku config: STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF:     STORMPATH_URL
STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID:     STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID
STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET: STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Windows command prompt, sorry. What you could do instead is manually set them to the correct values, eg: `heroku config:set STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF=xxx`, then run: `heroku config:set STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID=xxx`, and finally: `heroku config:set STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET=xxx`

Comment: Manual setting gives me this: "error:  name=ResourceError, status=401, code=401, userMessage=Authentication required., developerMessage=Authentication with a valid API Key is required., moreInfo=http://www.stormpath.com/docs/quickstart/connect, message=HTTP 401, Stormpath 401 (http://www.stormpath.com/docs/quickstart/connect): Authentication with a valid API Key is required."  Should I try something other than Heroku?